# Blender crashes everytime i want to play the animation. Can somebody help?

Tags: animation, mixamo

Everytime i start to play the animation with the carpet falling down blender crashes. I dont why. Here i uploaded the file maybe someone can help.
Here is the Link: https://we.tl/t-rZSbZZb21d

[image]

Comment: Your file is very big (500 MB) for such a simple scene. I'm not sure why. The freezing/crash is caused by *Joe* the character model. It looks low-poly but it has over 300k. Especially the shoes are high-poly. While the shirt lacks the needed geometry badly. I guess you have made Joe low-poly and added a *Subdivision*, and a *Solidify* modifier. That's ok. But when you exported the model to Mixamo the modifiers had been applied and made Joe high-poly. That's bad. Better export Joe without the modifiers and add them back when you re-import the Mixamo model. This way the model stays low-poly.

Comment: I also recommend watching a few tutorials about character modeling and topology. For physics simulation and animation, you should apply the *Scale*, *Rotation*, and *Location* (Ctrl+A in *Object* mode) and place your model at the world origin (0,0,0). The same for the blanket. Give it a good simple quad topology, make sure the normals point outside (face orientation), and apply the *Scale*. Then the simulation should work much better.

Comment: thank u for ur informations